# Single/complete Maven dependencies for Java EE 5 API

Tags: java, maven, jboss5.x, java-ee-5

Is there a single maven dependency containing whole Java EE 5 spec API. Just like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

for Java EE 6.

I'm using JBoss 5 and want to add single (or several) dependency as `provided` scope and be sure that I have everyting that is available in JBoss.

Maybe some kind of archetype exist for JBoss 5.x.x deployed project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on maven central I think you need the following:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javaee</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you know is it the same as `com.sun.j2ee:javaee:1.5` ?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. I've never seen or used com.sun.j2ee:javaee:1.5. Here is the link to the official repository where the groupId and artifactId are as in my answer: http://download.java.net/maven/2/javaee/javaee-api/5/