# Maven repository artifact: jboss-j2ee

Tags: java, maven, jboss, java-ee-5, jboss-4.2.x

Question regarding Maven Repository and Java EE specification.

I just saw this question: [Single/complete Maven dependencies for Java EE 5 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177131/single-complete-maven-dependencies-for-java-ee-5-api) and checked our project.

We are on JBoss 4.2.2 and using a jboss-j2ee artifact.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-j2ee</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

What puzzled me was that this is the last version I could find for jboss-j2ee when [searching the central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22jboss%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jboss-j2ee%22).

I thought it might be listed under a different Artifact ID (J2EE vs Java EE rebranding), so I looked up all [artifacts for Group ID of `jboss`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22jboss%22).

It appears that 4.2.2.GA is the latest version for any Artifact.  Does anyone know why this is?  Did JBoss stop publishing artifacts to Maven repositories?

At some point, we will want to upgrade JBoss, and it will be important to know where I can find dependencies.

In this particular scenario, I could just use the Java EE 5 or Java EE 6 API, but I am just curious as to why I cannot find *any* JBoss artifacts past 4.2.2 on the central repository.

Thanks very

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the JBoss Maven Repository instead.

http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss